# How to Debug in Android Studio?

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio

How can I

1. Set a breakpoint.
2. Stop on Breakpoint.
3. Release, but leave in debug mode. By release, I mean don't step to next line. Jump to next breakpoint. Or just wait until a breakpoint is hit

I have no time or desire to go diving into the SDK classes. I just want out after I have stepped through a few lines. So far the only thing I have been able to do is just killing the debug session.  Where is the "RELEASE" button to just move on?

I mean to me this is just obvious.  You don't want to step deeper and deeper into the code. Once your done looking just resume into debug mode. Wait until you hit another break point.  How do I do this? Can it be done? And why is there no button for this?

Just resume, stay in debug mode. How do you do this?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/intl/ko/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html Clicking on the column to the left of the code (where you might have line numbers) toggles breakpoints at that line. Once you hit a break point the controls for stepping/resuming/etc become available. Resume/Pause/Stop are in the vertical set of buttons on the left, while stepping controls are horizontal along the top of the debugging pane.

Comment: Docs are good, but they don't cover the most common case. You just goto spot breakpoint you want to debug then resume debugging  when done looking at variables. That way you can jump to next point or even circle back and check the values again.    This is upper left button. the green arrowe on the left hand side is the resume button I was looking for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The top left button in the debug window (the green triangle) is doing what you want. "Resume Program (F9)"

Answer (score 4):

Breakpoints are toggled by clicking in the narrow column to the left of the code. You can also have conditional breakpoints, for example by right clicking the red spot I could enter `someVariable > someOtherVariable`. Other options include suspending the whole app, or just the thread that encountered the breakpoint.
[image]

**Buttons going down the left**

- Resume
- Pause
- Stop
- View breakpoints
- Mute breakpoints

**Buttons across the top**

- Show execution point
- Step over
- Step into
- Force step into
- Step out

[image: debugger]

Answer (score 0):

you should do the followings to enable the debugger option - https://developer.android.com/studio/debug