# ImageView appears too late

Tags: java, android, imageview, sharedpreferences

I Programm a Quiz App it starts with the Activty (Quiz Activity). I already set up that if the highscore is over 10, an ImageView will be shown permanently in Menu2 Activity. That works very fine also on restart of the app, the only problem is that if the user reaches a highscore for example 12 the ImageView (trophy1)will not immediately shown. The picture appears when the user hits directly after the highscore of for example 2. then the picture rests there permanently.. How can i set up that it appears directly when the highscore >10 is reached=

Quiz Activity java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

    //Randomizes the row of the questions
    QuestionLibrary q = new QuestionLibrary();
    System.out.printf("Question:0 Choice:(%s, %s, %s) Answer:%s%n",
            q.getChoice1(0), q.getChoice2(0), q.getChoice3(0), q.getCorrectAnswer(0));
    q.shuffle();
    System.out.printf("Question:0 Choice:(%s, %s, %s) Answer:%s%n",
            q.getChoice1(0), q.getChoice2(0), q.getChoice3(0), q.getCorrectAnswer(0));
    mQuestionLibrary.shuffle();
    //End randomizer

    //We need this for the NAVIGATION DRAWER
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.nav_action);

    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);

    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);
    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); //Able to see the Navigation Burger "Button"

    NavigationView mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nv1);
    mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem){
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                case(R.id.nav_stats): //If nav stats selected Activity 2 will show up
                    Intent accountActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Menu2.class);
                    startActivity(accountActivity);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    //Initialize

    mScoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score_score);
    mQuestionView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
    mButtonChoice1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice1);
    mButtonChoice2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice2);
    mButtonChoice3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice3);

    updateQuestion(); //New question appears

    //Start of Button Listener1 -> if true, next question appears +score +1[] Else menu 2 will show
    mButtonChoice1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (mButtonChoice1.getText() == mAnswer) {
                mScore = mScore + 1;
                updateScore(mScore);
                updateQuestion();

                Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Wrong... Try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, Menu2.class);
                intent.putExtra("score",mScore); //pass score to Menu2
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
    //End of Button Listener1

    //Start of Button Listener2
    mButtonChoice2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (mButtonChoice2.getText() == mAnswer) {
                mScore = mScore + 1;
                updateScore(mScore);
                updateQuestion();

                Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Oh... wrong your score is 0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, Menu2.class);
                intent.putExtra("score",mScore); //pass score to Menu2
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
    //End of Button Listener2

    //Start of Button Listener3
    mButtonChoice3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //My logic for Button goes in here

            if (mButtonChoice3.getText() == mAnswer) {
                mScore = mScore + 1;
                updateScore(mScore);
                updateQuestion();

                //This line of code is optional...
                Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Come on, that was not so hard...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, Menu2.class);
                intent.putExtra("score",mScore); //pass score to Menu2
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
    //End of Button Listener3

}


private void updateQuestion() {
        //If the max. number of questions is reached, menu2 will be open if not  a  new quiz selection appears
   if (mQuestionNumber < mQuestionLibrary.getLength()) {
        mQuestionView.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getQuestion(mQuestionNumber));
        mButtonChoice1.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice1(mQuestionNumber));
        mButtonChoice2.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice2(mQuestionNumber));
        mButtonChoice3.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice3(mQuestionNumber));

        mAnswer = mQuestionLibrary.getCorrectAnswer(mQuestionNumber);
        mQuestionNumber++;
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Last Question! You are very intelligent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, Menu2.class);
        intent.putExtra("score",mScore); //pass score to Menu2
        startActivity(intent);


    }

}

private void updateScore ( int point){
    mScoreView.setText("" + mScore);
    //Shared preferences = a variabe (mScore) gets saved and call up in another activity
    SharedPreferences mypref =getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    int highScore = mypref.getInt("highScore", 0);
    if(mScore> highScore){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mypref.edit();
        editor.putInt("currentscore", mScore);
        editor.apply();
    }
}

    @Override //Makes that the "Burger" Item, shows the Drawer if someone clicks on the simbol
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){
        if (mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

Menu 2:

```
public class Menu2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout2;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private Button popup;
    private PopupWindow popupWindow;private LayoutInflater layoutInflater; //Alows to add a new layout in our window

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu2);

        TextView txtScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textScore2);
        TextView txtHighScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textHighScore);
        ImageView imgTrophyView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.trophy1);
        ImageView imgTrophyView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.trophy2);
        Button bttPOPUP = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enablePOPUP);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int mScore = intent.getIntExtra("score", 0);
        txtScore.setText("Your score is: " + mScore);

        SharedPreferences mypref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        int highScore = mypref.getInt("highScore", 0);
        if (highScore >= mScore)
            txtHighScore.setText("High score: " + highScore);
        else {
            txtHighScore.setText("New highscore: " + mScore);

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mypref.edit();
            editor.putInt("highScore", mScore);
            editor.commit();
        }

        if (highScore >= 10) {
            imgTrophyView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bttPOPUP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        if (highScore >= 20) {
            imgTrophyView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }


        popup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.enablePOPUP);
        popup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                layoutInflater =(LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup)layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_menu2_1,null);
                popupWindow = new PopupWindow(container,1000,980,true); //400,400=popUp size, true = makes that we can close the pop up by simply click out of the window
                popupWindow.showAtLocation(mDrawerLayout2, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                mDrawerLayout2.setAlpha((float) 0.1);

                container.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){

                    @Override

                    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent  ){
                        mDrawerLayout2.setAlpha((float) 1);
                        popupWindow.dismiss();

                        return true;

                    }

                });


                popupWindow.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss() {
                        mDrawerLayout2.setAlpha((float) 1);
                        popupWindow.dismiss();

                    }
                });
            }
        });

        mToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.nav_action);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        mDrawerLayout2 = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout2);

        mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout2, R.string.open, R.string.close);
        mDrawerLayout2.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
        mToggle.syncState();
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        NavigationView mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(nv2);
        mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem){
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                    case(R.id.nav_home2):
                        Intent accountActivity2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),QuizActivity.class);
                        startActivity(accountActivity2);

                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Menu2.this, QuizActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    @Override //Makes that the "Burger" Item, shows the Drawer if someone clicks on the simbol
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the point parameter?

Comment: Shouldn't you move/copy `imgTrophyView1.setVisibility` into the updateScore method?

Comment: I tried to copy it into the updateScore method but now nothing happens

Comment: @cricket_007 I do not exactly now that, another person said me to do that....

Comment: If you want the image to show when highScore >= 10, then as far as I can tell, Menu2 already does that. If you only want greater than 10, then update the conditional... It's hard to find the issue here without a [mcve]

Comment: @cricket_007   It does it fine, the only problem it shows it but only if the user makes the highscore  and than restarts the quiz and for exampled does a highscore of 3 and not before... I want that It does that when the highscore s hitten not later..

Comment: Then set breakpoint in your code and watch the value in the SharedPreferences... Is it as you expect when you reach the high score? Or is that Intent score value always less than it? Also, if you want to "go back" to the quiz activity, you should use `finish()` rather than startActivity

Comment: @cricket_007  How can i nsert the breakpoint/ watch the value of the Prefs?

Comment: Fire up the debugger. Super useful tool to learn for any Java programming https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32902702/how-to-debug-in-android-studio

Comment: Does not work for me to start the debugger

Comment: Well, don't know what to tell you... Is `mAnswer` a String? You cannot use `==` to compare strings and `getText() == mAnswer` doesn't compare the correct values

Comment: Well but that works, the only problem is that the picture appears to late... @cricket_007

Comment: I really don't understand "too late", sorry. Your numbers don't match what you expect. And without a [mcve], no one here can really run your code

Comment: @cricket_007I will explain it. So when i play my quiz, and I reach the score of 10 **the ImageView** shuld be VISIBLE. But that does not happen. Then when i press on retry Quiz and make a score of for example 3 the Imageview appears..

Answer (score 0):

This line...

```
editor.putInt("currentscore", mScore);
```

What is that doing? You never get the value of `"currentscore"` anywhere...

Should that actually be `"highScore"`?

For example, that would be simpler to diagnose with String constants

```
public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String PREFS = "QuizPrefs";
    public static final String KEY_HIGH_SCORE = "highScore";
    public static final String KEY_CURRENT_SCORE = "score";
    private SharedPreferences pref;

    private int mScore;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        ...

        this.prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);

    }

...

private void updateScore(){
    mScoreView.setText(String.valueOf(mScore));
    int highScore = prefs.getInt(KEY_HIGH_SCORE, 0);
    if(mScore > highScore){
        prefs.edit().putInt(KEY_HIGH_SCORE, mScore).apply();
    }
}

private void endQuiz() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, Menu2.class);
    intent.putExtra(KEY_CURRENT_SCORE, mScore); //pass score to Menu2
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

---

Then, in the next Activity, use your constants and check the correct values

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int score = intent.getIntExtra(QuizActivity.KEY_CURRENT_SCORE, 0);
    txtScore.setText("Your score is: " + score);

    SharedPreferences mypref = getSharedPreferences(QuizActivity.PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    int highScore = mypref.getInt(QuizActivity.KEY_HIGH_SCORE, 0);
    if (highScore >= score)
        txtHighScore.setText("High score: " + highScore);
    else {
        txtHighScore.setText("New highscore: " + score);
        mypref.edit().putInt(QuizActivity.KEY_HIGH_SCORE, score).apply();
    }

    if (highScore >= 10) {
        imgTrophyView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        bttPOPUP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    if (highScore >= 20) {
        imgTrophyView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Comment: Why would I answer if I think it didn't? You need to use the correct key. The reason your code works after you "go back and forth" is that you have `editor.putInt("highScore", mScore);` in Menu2 updating the correct key

Answer (score 0):

If your image size is large, it may take time to load it making it less user friendly.

Tweak to make it fast:

- Move the image from 'drawable' folder to 'drawable-nodpi' folder in the resource directory. Create a folder named 'drawable-nodpi' if it's now yet created.
- The reason is because it will automatically change the size of the image according to the device.

Comment: Hello, that is surely not the problem Sir... The image is very little..